# Why I have a TypeError with my rail actions helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, helper, typeerror

Ruby version :

```
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
```

Rails version :

```
Rails 4.1.4
```

Hello,

I've made a helper for my basic admin controller actions in my admin index views.

*application_helper.rb*

```
(...)
def actions_helper(object)
  show_link = link_to "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-file\"></span>".html_safe, [:admin, object], :class => 'btn btn-primary', :title => 'Voir '+@model_singular_name
  edit_link = link_to "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></span>".html_safe, [:edit, :admin, object], :class => 'btn btn-primary', :title => 'Modifier '+@model_singular_name
  destroy_link = link_to "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span>".html_safe, [:admin, object], :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Voulez-vous supprimer '+@model_singular_name+'?' }, :class => 'btn btn-primary', :title => 'Supprimer '+@model_singular_name
  "<p class=\"btn-group btn-group-xs\">".html_safe+show_link+edit_link+destroy_link+"</p>".html_safe
end
(...)
```

It works well for my admin pages controller, here is the view:

*views/admin/pages/index.html.haml*

```
(...)
%td.col-sm-1
  = actions_helper(page)
(...)
```

And here is the result in my browser :

```
<td class="col-sm-1 tac">
  <p class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/admin/pages/linge-de-lit" title="Voir la page">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/admin/pages/linge-de-lit/edit" title="Modifier la page">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-confirm="Voulez-vous supprimer la page?" data-method="delete" href="/admin/pages/linge-de-lit" rel="nofollow" title="Supprimer la page">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    </a>
  </p>
</td>
```

But when I try do the same thing with my product admin controller, I have a TypeError, here is the view :

*views/admin/products/index.html.haml*

```
(...)
%td.col-sm-1
  = actions_helper(product)
(...)
```

And here is my log error :

```
ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
    58:             .badge.background-danger.
    59:               %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-list-alt
    60:       %td.col-sm-1.
    61:         = actions_helper(product)
  app/helpers/application_helper.rb:34:in `+'
  app/helpers/application_helper.rb:34:in `actions_helper'
  app/views/admin/products/index.html.haml:61:in `block in _app_views_admin_products_index_html_haml__1562039986179127831_70358450305840'
  app/views/admin/products/index.html.haml:24:in `_app_views_admin_products_index_html_haml__1562039986179127831_70358450305840'
```

I don't think the problem is in my controller or my each method because when I ask to my actions_helper to only return `#{object}`, the result for my admin page controller is  `#&lt;Page:0x000000035ccaf8&gt;` and for my admin product controller `#&lt;Product:0x007ffb3618c480&gt;`.

**UPDATE**

Here is my admin products controller :

*controller/admin/products_controller.rb*

```
class Admin::ProductsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :check_favorite, :uncheck_favorite, :check_shop_disponibility, :uncheck_shop_disponibility, :check_web_disponibility, :uncheck_web_disponibility]

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @pages = Page.all
  end

  def edit
    @pages = Page.all
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    if @product.save
      redirect_to [:admin, @product], notice: 'Product was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @product.update(product_params)
      redirect_to [:admin, @product], notice: 'Product was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    redirect_to admin_products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  def check_favorite
    @product.update(favorite: true)
    redirect_to admin_products_url
  end

  def uncheck_favorite
    @product.update(favorite: false)
    redirect_to admin_products_url
  end

  def check_shop_disponibility
    @product.update(shop_disponibility: true)
    redirect_to admin_products_url
  end

  def uncheck_shop_disponibility
    @product.update(shop_disponibility: false)
    redirect_to admin_products_url
  end

  def check_web_disponibility
    @product.update(web_disponibility: true)
    redirect_to admin_products_url
  end

  def uncheck_web_disponibility
    @product.update(web_disponibility: false)
    redirect_to admin_products_url
  end

  private

    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :brand_id, :price, :minimum_price, :shop_disponibility, :web_disponibility, :purchase_link, :favorite, :page_ids => [], :post_ids => [])
    end
end
```

Here is my routes.rb :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  concern :change_priority do
    member do
      patch :increase_priority
      patch :decrease_priority
    end
  end
  concern :change_favorite do
    member do
      patch :check_favorite
      patch :uncheck_favorite
    end
  end
  concern :change_visibility do
    member do
      patch :check_visibility
      patch :uncheck_visibility
    end
  end
  concern :change_disponibility do
    member do
      patch :check_shop_disponibility
      patch :uncheck_shop_disponibility
      patch :check_web_disponibility
      patch :uncheck_web_disponibility
    end
  end
  namespace :admin do
    root 'dashboard#index'
    resources :brands
    resources :pages, concerns: [:change_priority, :change_favorite, :change_visibility]
    resources :posts, concerns: [:change_priority, :change_favorite, :change_visibility]
    resources :products, concerns: [:change_favorite, :change_disponibility]
  end

  root 'welcome#index'
  get 'contact' => 'contact#index'

  get '/:id', to: 'categories#show', as: 'category'
  get '/:category/:id', to: 'pages#show', as: 'page'

end
```

Comment: Could you add relevant parts of your routes.rb? It may help.

Comment: @MathieuLeTiec Paste your product admin controller please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `@model_singular_name` is nil. Make sure it's set somewhere.